# RVM & Rails 3 - rails command fires error: Is a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I installed Rails 3 by following this gist: http://gist.github.com/296055

But when I try "rails" in terminal I get the following error:

```
/Users/yves/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/rails: Is a directory - /Users/yves/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activerecord-3.0.0/lib/rails (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /usr/bin/rails:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/rails:19
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE

Ok, I figured out something. I can run the correct rails by going directly to the right executable: 
/Users/yves/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/rails-3.0.0/bin/rails

Apparantly my "rails" command is still linked another version, the one in usr/local/bin

How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out my answer on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648392/install-rails-3-on-osx-with-rvm/3652137#3652137):

(if this works for you, we should mark this as a duplicate question.  But I don't have enough points to do that myself)

--

Older versions of rvm had a bug that can cause your ruby versions to get crosswired because the OS can cache executable paths for the **which** command (particularly if you are using zsh). See this [long, detailed, mind blowing post](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/08/24/a-tale-of-abort-traps-or-always-question-your-assumptions/) by Yehuda Katz on the subject.

What I had to do this morning:

```
rvm update && rvm reload # update rvm
rvm gemset delete rails3 # delete old gemset
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm gemset create rails3
rvm use 1.9.2@rails3
which ruby          # check to be sure the ruby interpretter is properly set to 1.9.2
hash -r             # if ruby interpretter is not pointing to 1.9.2
gem install rails
which rails         # check to be sure we are using rvm version of rails
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this article](http://ignar.name/articles/2010/08/10/-ruby-1-9-2-rails-3-rvm/) and was able to install everything. The article is in Russian, but you should be able to translate it to desired language via Google translate.
I bumped into 'no ssl' error but this article explains how to resolve it as well (at the bottom).

My setup now is:

1. RVM
2. Ruby 1.8.7 + Rails 2.3.8
3. Ruby 1.9.2 + Rails 3.0.0

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I read the post, but there is nothing in there that I did different or says about my error..