# Installing Ruby 1.9.2 through RVM fails

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

I installed RVM following the official guide on [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). I installed Ruby 1.8.7 with `rvm install 1.8.7` and then set it as default with `rvm 1.8.7 --default`.

Then I tried to install 1.9.2 with `rvm install 1.9.2`, and also tried `rvm install 1.9.2-head`. Everything went fine until I got to the "ruby-1.9.2-head - #installing-part".

Then I got a huge error list complaining about my *nix bash commands:

```
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1760: sed: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1762: mv: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1762: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1632: cp: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 233: mkdir: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 237: date: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 233: mkdir: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 237: date: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1736: mkdir: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1738: ln: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1760: sed: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1762: mv: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1762: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1760: sed: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1762: mv: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1762: chmod: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 233: mkdir: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 237: date: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1562: cp: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1573: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1562: cp: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1573: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1562: cp: command is not
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1573: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1562: cp: command not found
/Home/Kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1573: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1562: cp: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1573: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1562: cp: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1573: chmod: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1562: cp: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/Manager: line 1573: chmod: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 276: mkdir: command not found
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 280: date: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
/Home/kevin/.rvm/scripts/utilities: line 656: cp: command not found
/Usr/bin/env: bash: The file or directory does not exist
```

If I enter `rvm 1.9.2 --default` I get the same error output and my `$PATH` variable is completely cleared.

Does anyone have a solution on this problem?

Comment: Did you unset `$PATH` or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reinstall and start fresh remove RVM, just do `rm -rfv ~/.rvm` and also `rm ~/.rvmrc` if it's there.

Maybe "[Install Rails 3 on OSX with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648392/install-rails-3-on-osx-with-rvm/)" will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it looks like the whole RVM script is broken. The `rvm install ree` command didn't fail but when running `rvm use ree` I started getting problems.

The `$PATH` variable is not empty, like with `rvm use 1.9.2`, but it missed some important paths like `/bin` and `/usr/bin`.

Here is an example console session:

```
calas@chamonix:~$ ls
Desktop  dev  Documents ...
calas@chamonix:~$ rvm use ree
info: Using /home/calas/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2010.02
calas@chamonix:~$ ls
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
calas@chamonix:~$ rvm info
Command 'sed' is available in '/bin/sed'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sed: command not found
bash: grep: No such file or directory
bash: mkdir: No such file or directory
bash: grep: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory
```

After running `rvm info` the `$PATH` variable is empty.

I removed the whole RVM installation with `rvm implode` and reinstalled but that didn't work.

I guess the solution is to downgrade or wait for a new release.

---

The solution is ready in the git source:

```
rvm update --head && rvm reload
```

and problem solved, thanks Wayne!

Comment: "I guess the solution is to downgrade or wait for a new release.", actually, you should contact the author to let him know if you are having problems and suspect it is RVM itself, after having double-checked the installation process.

Comment: Sure, that was the solution then, I contacted Wayne on IRC, he was very kind and came with a solution in less than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "[How to install Ruby on Rails in Ubuntu 11.10](http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/27/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-11-10/)" will help you.

Comment: I would recommend following the [standard RVM installation](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) steps first, then, if those don't work, look to see what someone else has said. I've seen some unhelpful ideas in blogs that cloud the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this just happened to me and, upon closer inspection, I was just missing `/user/bin` on my path. But why?

Turns out, after some investigation, ***I was missing a colon before `$PATH`*** and this caused the first directory in the default path (i.e. /user/bin) to get omitted.

Once I changed this:
`export PATH=$SCRIPTS:$WORKSPACE:$ANDROID_HOME:$HEROKU$PATH`
to this:
`export PATH=$SCRIPTS:$WORKSPACE:$ANDROID_HOME:$HEROKU:$PATH`

(notice the colon added before the last '$')
Everything worked again. Obviously, your path will vary but check for missing colons.