# Rails3 RVM and zsh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm, zsh

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 64bit and have just switched over to using ZSH today. After I logged out and back in to load the new zsh I experienced this problem:

```
/home/map7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/map7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
    from /home/map7/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

This problem is very similar to:
[Install Rails 3 on OSX with RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648392/install-rails-3-on-osx-with-rvm)

I have fixed the problem using the answer from that post but I would like to know if I'm doing this correctly and if there is a better way?

After completing these steps (thanks to marshally):

```
rvm update && rvm reload 
rvm gemset delete rails3
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm gemset create rails3
gem install rails
rvm use 1.9.2@rails3
```

Then I entered command

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

I still had to add the following to my .zshrc file:

```
[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm

rvm use 1.9.2@rails3
```

Should I have to enter these lines into the .zshrc for it to work? It seems like a work around?

I have tried 'rvm use 1.9.2@rails3 --default' but the problem still happens when opening a new terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need the `rvm use 1.9.2@rails3` line in your .zshrc.

I believe the problem mentioned in that post has been fixed in the current version of RVM, so that shouldn't be an issue anymore. With only the `[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in your .zshrc, do you get the original error message, or is it just that your default gemset is not set?

Comment: I can remove the rvm use 1.9.2@rails3 but I must have these two lines in the .zshrc:
'[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm' and 'rvm 1.9.2'

Comment: I also noticed that I had rails installed in the /usr/bin/rails directory to, which was never a problem when using bash. So I had to switch over to rvm system and uninstall that gem.

Comment: I no longer need the 'rvm use 1.9.2@rails3'. It could be that I've updated my packages a few times since this question and most likely RVM as part of that and the problem has gone away.